# pg_restore FATAL: terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a 10G directory pg dump and I'm trying to restore it with the following command:

`docker-compose exec db pg_restore --user=postgres -C -c -O -F d -j 4 -d MyDB /tmp`

The restore appears to be working for around 3 minutes, but then exits with the following error:

`ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request`

Then it closes with

```
FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost
FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost
FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost
```

How can I fix this?

**Important Info**

Last night this restore worked fine when using my SSD. However, I ran out of space on my SSD so I switched to my larger (but slower) HDD. I'm only now getting this error on my HDD. Is there a reason why switching from a SSD to a HDD would create this error?

Comment: Did you ever work what was the cause of this issue? I'm seeing something similar I think.